# D3.js: Mouse over between grid lines

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a line chart with grid lines. Here's the similar example: http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940
I need to change the background of vertical space between X(2) to X(4), X(8) to X(10) and X(12) to X(14) on mouse hover. But I am not able to understand how to use D3 to reference those spaces between the grid lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing there to click on/hover over. The normal axis/grid creates lines, not rectangles. You would need to change the default behave of the axis objects to create "invisible, but clickable" rectangles in order to be able to attach a mouse event to those spaces.

I don't know if this is the recommended approach but it seems like it could work. After the axis has been created:

```
something
    .attr('class','xaxis')
    .call(xAxis)
```

You could select the ticks with something like this:

```
d3.select(svg).select('.xaxis g.tick').each(function(){
    // this.transform will be "translate(X,Y)"
})
```

In the function you can query the existing properties of the `g` elements and extract the `transform` attribute which will contain the X and Y offset for the "tick". This can be used to determine one dimension of your rectangle objects. The other dimension is determined by the size of the other axis or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne. Any pointers on how should I go about adding invisible rectangles?